# How to force 'create_bulkloader_config' to pickup latest schema/data?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have gone through the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata) to create a bulkconfig from my schema in order to download and upload some data to GAE.

I made some changes to my schema and republished it. I have deleted all my previous records in `Datastore Viewer`. And I have waited for an hour.

and still when I run this command to create a bulkconfig according to my latest schema, it still only reflects the old models.

```
appcfg.py create_bulkloader_config --filename=bulkloader.yaml --url=http://your_app_id.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api
```

What do I have to do to force it to get the latest? Or is it just a waiting game due the high replication database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per google documentation, when you generate the config doc using "create_bulkloader_config" , the generation of "bulkloader.yaml" is based on your datastore statistics. When you change your datastore schema, the datastore statistics could still reflect the old schema and may take upto 24 hours to be updated based on the new one. This could be the reason for your observation. What do you see in your datastore statistics tab (not datastore viewer) , when you are getting the above observation?

Comment: After nearly three hours waiting, still the same problem. You might be right though. Statistics doesn't show the new fields yet. Even though I have data with the new fields in there. It says `Last updated: 1 day, 4:15:26 ago`  Thats a loooong time for the schema to be picked up. What a shame.

Comment: `Last updated: 1 day, 22:32:36 ago`, they claim the statistics should update less than a day. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Seeing the same osbservation across all my app engine apps. Hope @proppy or someone from app engine team can confirm if this is expected behaviour or currently there is an issue ?

Comment: I thought switching from AWS to GAE would be a good idea.  But it seems there is no real support. `Last updated: 2 days, 23:11:37 ago` I even posted on google groups, no one responds. I even created a new application and uploaded my code there. The statistics doesn't work there neither. It has failed completely.

Comment: I think the datastore statistics were refreshed within last 24 hours. Has this fixed the issue you were facing?

Comment: thanks a lot. It did solve it. After nearly 5 days waiting, the statistics are back alive. Funny enough yesterday someone from google responded on google groups that high replication datastore are not reliable to work with bulkloader, but he admitted that statistics were broken. Having said that, we are moving from AWS to GAE and would like to use high replication datastore. So if we are't supposed to use the bulkloader, what other option do we have to import our existing data into GAE?

Comment: nice to know its working now. maybe you can mark above answer as accepted so that future readers can easily know that they need to check datastore statistics update status to know what schema will be used by bulkloader. even i am curious to know what approach does google officially recommend for migrating bulk data to HRD

Comment: Thanks Tony. I accepted and +1 ;)  Indeed Statistics are 100% related to the bulkloader. It is the elephant in the room that google seems not want to recognize to exist.