# What happens when a function in GAE app exceeds quota yet is unfinished?

Tags: google-app-engine

I ran a function that loads a lot of data to GAE using db.put(). However, it raised over quota exception when I hit my write quota. When I rechecked the data by running the app, the data returned was indeed incomplete. So when the quota is available again, I ran the data loader again from some index (so I don't write the same data again and again).

Here is the problem: after I ran the data loader manually (again and again), it seems all the data that I need for the app to work is already there, although the first time I load the data there was over quota exception.

So, my question specifically is: does function that ran over quota in GAE being queued until the quota is available again or does it being terminated?

Background of project: my friend and I are building a search system. We need the database of the search system, thus we load the database to GAE.

Comment: please clarify my understanding. For example, on a particular day you tried to write entities from 1 to 100 into the datasore, but you hit the write quota limit on writing 80 entities. Now when you read, you see only entities 1 to 80 in the datastore. Now next day when quota are reset, you write more data, but from say 101 to 200 and then when you read you find that your datastore is already having data from 1 to 100 and not just 1 to 80, even though you did not explicitly write 81 to 100 again. Is this the observation? Also are you running any jobs or queues?

Comment: Yes. I wrote all entities (1 to end). It hit quota I don't know where, and datastore admin shows I have 925 entities, but compared to local running app, the search result differed. The next day, I ran from index 1 to 1000 then 1000 to 2000. The 1000-2000 hit quota again. Yet, the datastore remains at 925 entities. 2000 was last index (putting >2000 yields none). After quota restored, I ran again 1000 to 2000 with no over quota, thus I should have full datastore. Yet the entities remains at 925 but when I compared it with local running app (thus no quota) the datastore becomes exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you hit write quota while adding many values to the datastore, the remaining values will not be saved anywhere and you will have to try again. **Datastore admin** shows the number of entities based on datastore statistics, but this will have a delay in being updated. Though officially it is mentioned as upto 24 hours, it can be even more as mentioned in [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275202/how-to-force-create-bulkloader-config-to-pickup-latest-schema-data/17277052?noredirect=1#comment25204802_17277052). So for finding if recently uploaded entities are present in the datastore, we cannot rely on datastore admin and need to query and find if a particular entity you added recently is present. Or else you can read the entity key value that is returned for each db.put() and use the last returned value to see which is the last successfully stored entity.

Comment: Thank you. It is indeed the update that is slow. Now it shows 2557 entities.